# stopping a countdown timer from restarting in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code that shows a countdown timer that should start at the minute 00 of every hour and ends at the minute 10.

```
@php
$dt = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
@endphp

    <script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2100 23:10:00").getTime();
var now = new Date("<?php echo $dt; ?>").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  now+= 1000

  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("timer10").innerHTML = 

   minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

}, 1000);
```

It is working fine, except that it doesn't stop at 00:00 , and it resets the timer starting again from 59:59. What should I add to stop the timer at 00:00 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never clearing your interval. You need to call the `clearInterval` function.

```
@php
$dt = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
@endphp

    <script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2100 23:10:00").getTime();
var now = new Date("<?php echo $dt; ?>").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  now+= 1000

  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("timer10").innerHTML = 

   minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
   if(minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    // the interval will stop at this point.
   }

}, 1000);
```